# AdMob Firebase, is it possible to personalize your ads?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads, personalization

I would to personalize my ads with AdMob.

Exemple:

-I have a shopping List and I would like to have ads that only shows food.

-I have a sport List and I would like to have ads that only shows things about sport.

-...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ads that Google shows can be personalized based on many factors, like the types of websites you visit or mobile apps you've installed. However, I do not believe you can set specific persionalization parameters from inside the app. An individual user can control their ads personalization from the Ads panel in the settings menu. If ad personalization is off, ads may still use non-personal data, such as your general location or the topics on the website or app you're looking at. What you can do from inside the app is targetting as stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting).